# How to bundle typescript-node-express application

Tags: node.js, typescript, bundling-and-minification, typescript2.2

I want to build a complete fullstack web app.
My server side code is in typescript.
I would like to configure my project such that it will be from the following structre:

- projectFolder/src/(server-side typescript files) - **contians an index.ts main file**
- projectFolder/public/(client-side code) - served from index.ts express code.
- projectFolder/**serverCodeBundle.js**

While I am working on my server side code I want some watch command to run in the backgorund and bundle all my ts files to some **serverCodeBundle.js** such that it would be sourcemapped to original ts files.

To keep things simple let's assume my server-side code looks like this(for simplicity I have ommited client code serving):

```
/src/index.ts:
 import {A} from './A'
 new A()

/src/A.ts:
 export class A {
   constructor() {
     throw new Error("A error")
   }
 }
```

Running nodemon serverCodeBundle.js an error message should appear specifying the error come from A.ts.

I have tried tsify[together with require("source-map-support").install() in the beginning of each ts file(and in index.ts only too) and sourcemap option on in tsconfig] but couldn't get it to work.

Is there any tsify configuration, yeoman generator or any other bundler which can do that?